# Unable to re-install VLC after a partial upgrade (12.04) due to broken packages

Tags: 12.04, package-management, vlc, partial-upgrade

I did a partial upgrade early this morning and followed all the steps trustingly because it usually doesn't cause problems after until now.

VLC was unexpectedly removed without my knowing. I tried to re-install it via terminal but it showed this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.2+git20120711+r286-0~r39~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libvlccore5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.2+git20120711+r286-0~r39~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.2+git20120711+r286-0~r39~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
      E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried doing it through the Software Center but it also gave me a similar message. How can I fix this and install VLC again?

I'm using ThinkPad R61i 64-bit 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **ppa:videolan/stable-daily** to install vlc, please consider that 64bit builds were still pending until 9 minutes before since the instant I'm writing.

To add repo, if you didn't add it before:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```