# VLC won't launch after upgrade to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, vlc, 15.10

Every time a new Ubuntu release comes out something bad happens to VLC (at lest for me). Last upgrade VLC just wouldn't install, now it installs but when I launch it nothing happens. I would like to know how to fix this issue and prevent future VLC issues on upgrade? when I launch VLC from terminal I get this:

```
VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision 3.0.0~~git20151020+r62120+34~ubuntu15.04.1)
```

And then nothing happens. I’m running Ubuntu 15.10.when I update the ppa information I get this:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: Probably broken packages. Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163043/unable-to-re-install-vlc-after-a-partial-upgrade-12-04-due-to-broken-packages?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: This fixed my recent issues. Thank you so much! Though it seems to have rolled me back to a previous version.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was able to help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your VLC config folder `~/.config/vlc`. Or try `vlc --ignore-config`.

Comment: nothing happens just this: VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (revision 3.0.0~~git20151020+r62120+34~ubuntu15.04.1). note I'm using 15.10 and it says 15.04